# Can't create folder in DCIM

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard

I dont know why my i am not able to create folder inside DCIM folder of external sd-card.The code I have written seems to work fine but I am not able to create a folder now.

Code to save image

```
 FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        File newFile=new File(file,"images");
        if(!newFile.exists()){
            newFile.mkdirs();
        }


        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Design"));
```

And due to which unable to share image.

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

t

Comment: what is the source of your image which you want to save, are you taking that from camera or from somewhere else???

Comment: '<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>'. That does not work. It should be <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">. </uses-permission>. Adapt the other too.

Comment: 'newFile.mkdirs();'. Example of bad programming. Check the return value of mkdirs and do not continue if it fails but display a Toast saying so.

Comment: @greenapps please write it so that i can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

That does not work. It should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">. </uses-permission>.
```

Adapt the other too